# GAE's base.Hash and io.ByteStreams

Tags: java, google-app-engine

GAE not works with:

```
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Hash;

import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.io.ByteStreams;
```

and my code:

```
byte[] inputBytes;
    try {
      inputBytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException err) {
      logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Feed read error 1", err);
      return null;
   } 
.....................
 try {
      return Long.toHexString(Hash.hash64(s.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException err) {
      // UTF-8 is unlikely to be unsupported
```

not works any more, how can I fix it?

Tried:

```
import com.google.common.io.ByteStreams;
import com.google.common.base.Hash;
```

but it IDE said:

> The import com.google.common.io cannot be resolved
>
> The import com.google.common.base.Hash cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `repackaged` classes yourself - they're there to provide a stable version of the libraries for use by the SDK, without interfering with your own copies. Include your own copy with your app, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

None of the classes you listed are on the [AppEngine's JRE whitelist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html), so you can not use them.

You will need to find some external library that implements the needed functionality.

Comment: The JRE whitelist only applies to classes that are part of the Java runtime; these aren't.